# Extract all data from request payload to get them in Controller arguments C# Asp Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, controller

There is an issue. Can I adjust controller action to receive all data (include properties in objects) in controller arguments.

What I mean
I have this information sent:

```
{exportInfo: {collectionId: 428713, id: "59f9d640fcbfc5540c015f39"}, format: "CSV"}
```

There are 3 properties in total: collectionId, id, format. I does not count 'exportInfo' as a property because I want extract inner properties from it

I have an Action on the server

```
public void action (int collectionId, string id, FileFormat format) 
{ //FileFormat is enum
   ...
}
```

I know that I can create a class with 'collectionId' and 'id' properties and use it in action declaration. But may be there is another way? 
I am sending POST request
I am using ASP Net MVC 5

Comment: First tag was version of .net your using this differs slightly between web api and MVC and Core.  I'm assuming from your data that this action is a Post and Not a Get but it would also be nice if you specified that.  Lastly to answer your question yes you don't need a class, but it might be easier on you if you mad file format a string, because web-api has trouble grabbing out multiple parameters from complex classes, granted you don't have multiple complex classes, but it there are some nuances associated with the model binder

Comment: johnny 5 I forgot said that FileFormat is an Enum, not a Class

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the data that is very likely to change, but still for some reason you want to grab that data, but at this very moment you don't know how it could look like. 
Then you can try to work with [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) objects.

For instance:

```
//Input: {"val":42}

    [HttpPost]
    public dynamic PostDynamic(dynamic value)
    {
        return value.val;
    }
```

returns 42.

But, as usual, you must be very precise when writing such code because accessing a field that is not defined in the dynamic object will lead to receiving null. 
E.g.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public dynamic PostDynamic(dynamic value)
    {
        return value.hello;
    }
```

will return null in case we don't have `hello` field in our `value` object.

There are a few [shortcomings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135160/shortcomings-of-using-dynamic-types-in-c) in using dynamic types in C#.

Afterwards, I suggest you take a look at [this article](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example), it would definitely improve your understanding of Model Binding in ASP.NET.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I meant. I have exact data set, I have described it in question. And I want to get this params in action but without creating a new Class, just 3 arg in row.

Comment: Could you provide valid link please? I have not access to the site by clicking it

Comment: @simplygood Oh, I got you: you want to pass multiple parameters into your API method. 
Natively WebApi does not support such functionality, take a look at this [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API) explaining what workarounds you can do.